# Django: To check if old password entered by the user is valid or not

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am able to check the `new_password1` and `new_password2`, but I am unable to check whether the old password entered by the user is right or not. As it is not giving me the `ValidationError` on old password on the django template. Please suggest me the condition that can be used on forms.py

This is forms.py

```
class ChangePasswordForm(forms.Form):
old_password = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':  'Password'}))

new_password1 = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':  'Password'}))

new_password2 = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':  'Password'}))      

def set_user(self, user):
    self.user = user
    
def clean(self):
   
    old_password = self.cleaned_data.get('old_password')
    valpwd = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
    valrpwd = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password2')

    if not old_password:
        raise forms.ValidationError({
            'old_password':"You must enter your old password."})
    
    elif valpwd != valrpwd:
        raise forms.ValidationError({
            'new_password1': 'Password Not Matched'})
    return self.cleaned_data
```

This is views.py

```
class PasswordsChangeView(FormView):
template_name = 'dashboard/password/password_change.html'
form_class = ChangePasswordForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard:admin_login')

def get_form(self):
    form = super().get_form()
    form.set_user(self.request.user)
    return form
```

This is change_password.html

```
 <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
         <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <h6>Old Password</h6>{{form.old_password}}
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
               <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span style="color:red">{{ form.old_password.errors }}</span>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <h6>New Password</h6> {{form.new_password1}}
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <h6>Re-Type Password</h6>
          {{form.new_password2}}
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <span class="fas fa-lock"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
         
            <span style="color:red">{{ form.new_password1.errors }}</span>
          
        </div> 
          {% comment %} {{ form.as_p }}  {% endcomment %}
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Change Password</button>

      </form>
```

Comment: FYI: You can make use of the built-in [`PasswordChangeView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordChangeView)

Answer (score 2):

There is a build_in check_password method in django. You have to use check_password() method with user instance.

It will be like:

```
if user.check_password(old_password):
  # you logic
else:
  # old password is not correct
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`check_password()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers). For example, in your `views.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib import messages

if check_password(current_password, request.user.password):
    new_password = form.cleaned_data['...']
    confirm_password = form.cleaned_data['...']
    
    if new_password == confirm_password:
        # write your code here
        update_session_auth_hash(request, request.user) # <-- This code will keep session when user change password
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Password confirmation doesnt match password.')
else: 
    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Invalid password.')
```

`django.contrib.auth.hashers` module also has a `make_password()` help you hash your password.